# Developing an app/game for iPad 3 in air

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ipad-3

I have a simple game that I am building in as3/air using flash develop, and I would like to be able to put it onto the iPad 3.

My question is, if I develop the app in a 1024 x 768 resolution, will it scale effectively when deployed onto an iPad 3?

All assets will be vector art, so losing quality from scaling isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you publish it out to with the param `fullscreen = true` then it will automatically scale up. Though just be sure to optimize everything to the fullest extent as vectors are pretty processing intensive.

But it also depends on the version the SDK you're using, the newer air 3.3 sdk i believe supports it.